# Number of characters in pointer

Tags: string, pointers, char, sizeof

This is very simple but I forgot since the last time i did it was two months ago. I want to know how you find the number of characters (letters) in a string pointer. I tried to use sizeof() and strlen() but they return the wrong value. For example, when insert="-dh o output -i input", the sizeof() function returns 210. I would greatly appreciate your help. My function:

```
int find(char* insert, char* check)
{

}
```

Comment: How is `strlen` returning the wrong value? :v
The algorithm of that function is to iterate over all characters until the `'\0'` character is found. After each iteration, it increments an `int` and returns that upon finding the `NIL` character.

Comment: when I do strlen(insert) it returns 210.

Comment: Could you post the full code with the call to find?

Comment: Sorry found my main found it in the main. the strlen() does work. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` should give the right answer (the length of the string) for a null-terminated string. `sizeof` is an operator, which in this case will return the number of bytes required to represent the `char` pointer.